# Laravel Datatables export button not working

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I am doing a Laravel project. And I am using datatables. I used following code to export the table in csv, excel and pdf but it's not working.

```
public function html ()
{
    return $this->builder ()
        ->columns ($this->getColumns ())
        ->addAction (['width' => '10%'])
        ->ajax ('')
        ->parameters ([
            'dom' => 'Bfrtip' ,
            'scrollX' => true ,
            'buttons' => [
                [
                    'extend' => 'collection' ,
                    'text' => '<i class="fa fa-download"></i> Export' ,
                    'buttons' => [
                        'csv' ,
                        'excel' ,
                        'pdf' ,
                    ] ,
                ] ,
                'colvis'
            ]
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Hey, ¿what are the errors you find?

Comment: @LuigiLopez not getting any error or any result...

Comment: I recommend you add an actual question or error message, right now it's very unclear what the problem is and what this code snippet is about.